# Пакетное редактирование атрибутов товаров в woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Как массово отредактировать атрибуты у товаров в woocommerce? Есть ли реально работающий плагин?

Answer (score 1):

Есть пара, и их спокойно можно найти в гугле:

- [PW WooCommerce Bulk
  Edit](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/pw-bulk-edit/)
- [WOOBE – Products Bulk Editor for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-bulk-editor/)

Comment: Похоже, оба плагина умеют это делать только в платной версии.